# How to do line plot for each column separately based on another column for each two samples for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as ,

i need something like this for each columns like stress , depression and anxiety and each participant data in each category

[image: samople out that i needed]

i wrote the python code as

```
ax = data_full.plot(x="participants", y=["Stress","Depression","Anxiety"],kind="line", lw=3, ls='--', figsize = (12,6)) 
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

get the output like this

[image: my script output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the participant column and merge it with the original data frame. Change the data frame to a data frame with only the columns you need in the merged data frame. Transform the data frame in its final form by pivoting. The resulting data frame is then used as the basis for the graph. Now we can adjust the x-axis tick marks, the legend position, and the y-axis limits.

```
dfs = pd.concat([df,df['participants'].str.split('_', expand=True)],axis=1)
dfs.columns = ['Stress', 'Depression', 'Anxiety', 'participants', 'category', 'group']
fin_df = dfs[['category','group','Stress']]
fin_df = dfs.pivot(index='category', columns='group', values='Stress')
# update
fin_df = fin_df.sort_index(ascending=False)
g = fin_df.plot(kind='line', title='Stress')
g.set_xticks([0,1])
g.set_xticklabels(['pre','post'])
g.legend(loc='center right')
g.set_ylim(5,25)
```

[image]

Comment: The key is to create the data for the graph. In that format, it will be a modification from a pandas plot. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: this works somehow for me but line goes from post to pre in plot. for example for participant 3 , it should come from 24 to 14  not 14 to 24. how can i solve this issue. ?

Comment: This can be done by reordering the data before drawing the graph. `fin_df = fin_df.sort_index(ascending=False)`